# Session Manager for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is anyone aware of a tool or plugin for managing different "sessions" in Eclipse, the way the "Session Manager" extension works for Firefox?

I use Eclipse for all my development, but I work on a lot of different projects. Some are for work while others for various hobbies and side projects. Whenever I switch, I have to close all the files and tabs associated with the old project and then reopen everything for the new one and then reverse that when I switch back. It gets very tedious.

Ideally, I'd like to "save" my current opened file editors as a named "session", and then close everything and open a previously saved session for a separate project, but I can't seem to find any Eclipse tool that does this.

Googling "eclipse session manager" just gets me a bunch of Java classes for code implementing related functionality in Jetty or Tomcat. Eclipse's "workspace" feature is close to what I need, but this just seems to separate the physical file locations and plugins associated with the projects. It doesn't actually save opened editors.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wanting exactly the same functionality, so I wrote a plugin.  I've been using it for a little while now.  It's still in beta.  Please see the instructions page that I have set up and get back to me with comments.

http://chrishull.com/projects/eclipse/

The source is on Github here

https://github.com/chrishull/github-eclipse

Share and enjoy;
-Chris

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, possibly since Java 11.